# AWS Lambda function call API in my local machine

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-vpc

I have a `Lambda` function that I want to call an API that is my machine, ex: `192.168.1.5/api/mymethod`

How can I create a `VPN` between `AWS` and my Network so Lambda can call it?

Any clue or tutorial on how to achieve this?

Comment: use openvpn to connect your local network with AWS

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a public IP on your local network, so that your AWS instances can connect to it.